# How do I create a Stacked Bar Chart using Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

could you please help how to create a stacked chart as per the image below? preferably in seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a','b','c','d'], 'total' : [30,50,30,50], 'match' : [5,12,14,22]})
df2
   ID total match
0   a   30  5
1   b   50  12
2   c   30  14
3   d   50  22
```

I just draw the 'a' and 'b' IDs..but need for all

[image]

Comment: Seaborn doesn't do stacked bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done it myself in matplotlib:

```
ax = df2.plot(x="ID", y="total", kind="barh")
df2.plot(x="ID", y="match", kind="barh", ax=ax, color="C2")
```

But would still prefer in seaborn:

[image]